# Continuous probability density function, how do I calculate $ E(X^n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is a math question about probability density function which is continuous. I would really appreciate help for this question.

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable which follows the following probability
density function: 
$$f(x) = e^{-x} \quad \quad when \quad x\ge0 \\\\f(x)=0 \qquad \quad \quad otherwise$$ 
1) For $n=${$1,2,3,...$}, establish a relationship between $E(X^{n})$ and $E(X^{n-1})$. Hence find $E(X^n)$. 
2) Find $E(X(X + 1)(X - 1))$ and $Var(4X + 1)$.

I have difficulty with the integration for $E(X^n)$. I'm not sure what to the with the power of n after doing integration by parts. I'm pretty sure it's linked to the $E(X^{n-1})$, but I don't know how so.
And for the second question, I don't even know from where to start.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: For (2) consider $E[X(X + 1)(X - 1)] = E[X^3 -X]$ and $\text{Var}(4X + 1) =\text{Var}(4X)=16\text{Var}(X)$

Comment: For (1) If you know the integral form of Gamma function, it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $E(X^n) = \int_0^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} dx = n\int_0^{\infty} x^{n-1} e^{-x} dx =n E(X^{n-1}) $

Comment: Right, but how can I find $E(X^n)$ or $E(X^{n-1})$? Does it have something to do with Gamma function? I have not learned that yet, so I don't think it should, but the only thing I can find to integrate $E(X^n)$ is with Gamma function.

Comment: You don't have to know Gamma function. Just integrate by parts: $ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} dx = [-x^n e^{-x}]_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} -n x^{n-1} e^{-x} dx $.

Then note that since $ E(X^n) = nE(X^{n-1}) $, it follows that $E(X^n) = n! E(X^0) = n!$

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that for any random variable for which the moments are defined, $$\operatorname{E}[X^n] = \left[\frac{d^n M_X(t)}{dt^n}\right]_{t=0},$$ that is to say, the $n^{\rm th}$ raw moment of $X$ is equal to the $n^{\rm th}$ derivative of the moment generating function of $X$ evaluated at $t = 0$.  Since $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{tx} e^{-x} \, dx = \int_{x=0}^\infty e^{(t-1)x} \, dx = \left[\frac{e^{(t-1)x}}{t-1}\right]_{x=0}^\infty = \frac{1}{1-t}, \quad t < 1,$$ it immediately follows that $$\operatorname{E}[X^n] = \frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left[(1-t)^{-1}\right]_{t=0} = n! \left[(1-t)^{-(n+1)}\right]_{t=0} = n!.$$  This isn't quite what the original question asked for, but it is illustrative of the usefulness of MGFs.